# Spring Thymeleaf doesn't process inline text variables

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I found in the documentation of Thymeleaf, that it's possible to use inline text variables, in http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining .

When I trying to show value of my variable with such code

```
<div>[[${myVar}]]</div>
```

it's showing me `<div>[[${myVar}]]</div>` on the rendered page, but if I use

```
<div th:utext="${myVar}"></div>
```

it's showing `<div>VALUE_OF_THE_VAR</div>` on the page.

I have SpringStandardDialect() enabled in my SpringTemplateEngine .

How to make Thymeleaf to process such inlinings?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the same [documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) you linked:

> In order for inlining to work, we must activate it by using the
>   th:inline attribute, which has three possible values or modes (text,
>   javascript and none). Let’s try text:

In your case, it should look like this:

```
<div th:inline="text">[[${myVar}]]</div>
```